# Use user data in cloudformation for 2016 windows ami

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, powershell-3.0

I am trying to add userdate to  run some custom script when I create a windows ec2 instance using cloudformation.  (Windows 2016)

```
 "UserData" : {
        "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : [
                "",
                [
                    "<powershell> \n",
                    "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\InitializeI‌​nstance.ps1 \n",
                    "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\create_folder.ps1 \n",
                    "New-Item -Path c:\\test3 -ItemType directory",
                    "</powershell>"
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
```

the above script does not seems to be working. 
Basically I need to run some custom script (which I already added in my base image) and some powershell command.

Answer (score 0):

By default the UserData section is not executed in 2016 Windows AMI.

You have to do the following steps manually;

1. Log-in to the instance. Open powershell terminal.
2. Go to the directory C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts.
3. Run
   `InitializeInstance.ps -Schedule` command.

After next start-up, the user-data section will be executed.

I believe now you encounter another issue that you can't manually login to the instance.
Then what you can do is create your own AMI by customizing Windows 2016 AMI with adding the following steps also.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html